# How to perform multiplication on char which represents a digit?

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, int

I am trying to convert a char digit to an integer: `{'1' -> 1, '2' -> 2, ..., '9' -> 9}` and then multiply that integer by another integer. This is my attempt so far.

```
#define toDigit(c) c - '0'

printf("%d\n", toDigit('3') * 5);
```

**Expected output**: 15

**Actual output**: -189

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

When your macro is expanded, the code looks like this:

```
printf("%d\n", '3' - '0' * 5);
```

at which point, the usual arithmetic precedence kicks in, and the multiplication happens first. So you get 51-(48*5), which gives the answer you see.

You could avoid this be putting your macro expansion in parantheses like this:

```
#define toDigit(c) ((c) - '0')
```

Ideally, avoid macros for this purpose. Or for any other purpose, for that matter. They are error prone, and can easily be replaced by a function, like this:

```
int toDigit(char c) { return c - '0'; }
```

You can use this inside complicated expressions without any issue.

Comment: Ideally the macro param `c` would be in parens as well. But really macros, just say no.

Comment: @john valid points, added that to answer, thanks.